# Kotlin error: 'LocationRequest.create()' not working despite updating LocationRequest.Builder

Tags: javascript, java, c#, kotlin, hubic-api

It asks me to update LocationRequest.Builder, but I change it and I still get an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY7Bv.png)

I tried the LocationRequest.Builder method, but it keeps getting an error

```
val locationRequest= LocationRequest.create().apply{
            interval =0
            fastestInterval=0
            priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            smallestDisplacement = if ()
        }
```

Which code would I replace it with, it's for andriod studio kotlin